# Typo or incorrect logic on protected questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, answers

I could be mistaken, but on [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79890/why-does-gmail-show-two-different-pictures-for-my-profile-one-of-which-is-not-m) page I see I need 10 rep to answer:

[image]

I have 25 rep and can't answer. I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 2):

Your source of rep is the association bonus, which is ignored when the check for protected questions is done. Hence, you cannot answer. This has been marked as [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design) over here [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions-because-i-gave-awa)